# Transform json to class intstance with class-transformer

Tags: json, typescript, class-transformer

I would like to create an instance of the Customer class from Json object.

But using the plainToInstance function of class-transformer I don't have the proper class instance as a type save typescript object.

What I'm doing bad?

**Import**

```
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';
```

**Customer JSON**

```
    const json = `{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Jogn",
      "surname": "Doe",
      "email": "j.doe.test@gmail.com",
      "phone": "123456789"
  }
}
`;
```

**Customer class definition**

```
import { Field, ObjectType, Directive, ID } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Address } from './address';

@ObjectType()
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
export class Customer {

  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  name: String;

  @Field({nullable: true})
  surname?: String;

  @Field()
  email: String;

  @Field({nullable: true})
  phone?: String;

  @Field()
  customerType: String;

  @Field()
  customerStatus: String;

  @Field(() => [Address], { nullable: true })
  addresses?: [Address]
}
```

**Transformation from Json to Customer instance**

```
let customer : Customer = plainToInstance(Customer, json) as Customer;
console.log('customer.email);
```

**Console result**

```
Customer email: undefined
```

> So I couldn't get the email of the customer here

**This is what I have when I log the entire customer variable**

console.log(customer);

```
{
      "id": "1",       
      "name": "Jogn",  
      "surname": "Doe",
      "email": "j.doe.test@gmail.com",
      "phone": "123456789"
}
```

**Test with creating the Customer instance inline**

```
var x = new Customer();
x.id = "123";
console.log(x)
```

*So, now the object looks properly in the console*

```
Customer { id: '123' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass a json object to `plainToInstance` - not a string.
i.e. your `json` variable should be

```js
const json = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'Jogn',
  surname: 'Doe',
  email: 'j.doe.test@gmail.com',
  phone: '123456789',
};
```

here's a working [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qf93c9?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

The second attribute of plainToInstance should be a plain object so you have to parse your json string into an object:

```
let customer = plainToInstance(Customer, JSON.parse(json))
```

Comment: Looks good, but I have an error: "Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)" Looks like there is a problem with <Customer>

Comment: Oh, yes. I've corrected it now.

Comment: @mazooma Just remove the type-parameters, typescript will anyway infer the correct types

Comment: @TmTron True, this works perfectly fine for me: let customer = plainToInstance(Customer, JSON.parse(json))